# Look Up, Match, Concatenate

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need a formula/function to concatenate cell values from one column and multiple rows. The matching criteria is applied to a different column. Here is my example of what I have to do:

Google Sheet #1

| Number | Disease |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Schizophrenia |
| 2 | Stroke |
| 3 | Anxiety |
| 4 | Bipolar |
| 5 | Hypertension |
| 22 | Asthma |

Google Sheet #2

| My Diseases | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,6 | Jane |
| 1,3,2 | Janet |
| 1 | Margaret |

End result needs to look like this:
On Google Sheet #2

| My Diseases | Name | Name of Diseases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,2,22 | Jane | **Schizophrenia, Stroke, Asthma** |
| 1,3,2 | Janet | **Schizophrenia, Anxiety, Stroke** |
| 1 | Margaret | **Schizophrenia** |

Basically, I need to match Google Sheet #2 to Google Sheet #1 and pullover the multiple matches according to the number into 1 cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that there is mistake in "Sheet #2" row 1 and instead of *1,2,6* it should be *1,2,22*

If all possible numbers in Sheet #2 column 1 are present in Sheet #1 database, then you can use:

```
=byrow(A9:A11,lambda(vl, TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,arrayformula(vlookup(SPLIT(vl,","),$A$1:$B$6,2,false)))))
```

If there are numbers missing, then change `VLOOKUP` to `XLOOKUP` with [missing_value] parameter:

```
=byrow(A9:A11,lambda(vl, TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,arrayformula(xlookup(SPLIT(vl,","),$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6,"Not found",0)))))
```

In both cases you can eliminate `BYROW`/`LAMBDA` and drag formula down or let to autofill, for example:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,arrayformula(vlookup(SPLIT(A9,","),$A$1:$B$6,2,false)))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth in Excel: `=BYROW(A9:A11,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,XLOOKUP(--TEXTSPLIT(x,","),$A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,"not found"))))`

Comment: Taught me something new with the TEXTJOIN() to start, thank you!